# Why does .equals() fail??? Checkers Game

Tags: java, while-loop, equals

I am currently working on a checkers game for a school project. The board is a 2 dimensional array of strings to represent the pieces on the board. Currently I am coding the rules for the game but for some reasons `.equals()` fails in the while loop.

```
 private static String redPawn = "redPawn";
 private static String blackPawn = "blackPawn";
 private static String redKing = "redKing";
 private static String blackKing = "blackKing"
 private static String[][] checkerPieces = new String[row][col];

 while(!redPawn.equals(checkerPieces[r][c]) || !redKing.equals(checkerPieces[r][c]))
    {
        System.out.println("You can only move the red pawns");
        playerInput.selectPiece();
    }
```

When debugging and putting only:

```
while(!redPawn.equals(checkerPieces[r][c]))
    {
        System.out.println("You can only move the red pawns");
        playerInput.selectPiece();
    }
```

It works until I add the conditional statement checking for a `redKing`. Can anyone help.

Comment: Can you add the error you're getting?

Comment: Could you tell us what is 'c' and 'r'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> for some reasons .equals() fails in the while loop.

This is because you use OR `||`, use AND `&&` instead

```
while(!redPawn.equals(checkerPieces[r][c]) && !redKing.equals(checkerPieces[r][c]))
```